# GUI That Runs PHP Files

Tags: php, visual-studio, user-interface

I have created a html page which sends custom data to a php file which then processes and evaluates it.

My next task is to make this into a GUI with the requirements:

```
1. A box for a custom search with button (it then posts this into the
php)

2. A box where xml/json request can be seen

3. A box where the xml/json response can be seen

4. A box where the parsed version is translated and made to look pretty.

 ***MUST CONNECT TO INTERNET, PHP ESTABLISHES CONNECTION BUT DO NOT WANT A GUI ISSUE
```

Any suggestions on programs or languages etc which can help me communicate with PHP in GUI form. It needs to be able to access the internet!

I was thinking perhaps Visual Basic as that's the only one I've ever used that really uses GUI's but I'm wondering what you all think!

Thanks!

Comment: If you decide to use simple HTML and JavaScript you have yourself a web application... A browser is a common application on most personal computers in our day and age.

Comment: Yes, I have that already. But it also requires a web server running on the computer. I'm looking to build a standalone version of this

Comment: PHP has a built-in server which might suffice for very rudimentary needs.

Comment: @joey please explain what you're referencing... to my understanding xampp or something similar that runs a php server is necessary. To further my point, I could not get my php scripts to work until I had installed xampp

Comment: @Joey - PHP's built-in server is only available in PHP5.4 and up. But more importantly, it's very specifically intended only for use as a development tool; suggesting it for use in a production system (even a rudimentary one) is not a good thing.

Comment: Spudly, I didn't get the impression they were building anything remotely like a production system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're asking for is a web browser, with a very simple little HTML/Javascript front-end web page to make the PHP calls and display the results. I'm not entirely sure what it is about a browser environment that makes you think it's unsuitable, but it's basically exactly what you're asking for.

If a full-blown web browser really isn't suitable, you could try using a web browser control inside a simple GUI app. This would still work exactly the same, but would be without the browser controls, such as the URL bar.

Comment: I like your second suggestion. You hit the nail on the head. I do not want there to be a URL bar (per my boss). Can you direct me to some information on creating a GUI app with no browser controL?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45487-creating-a-web-browser-in-vbnet/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a browser.

If you don't want to do that -- build a browser.

Comment: Oh building it sounds like fun!  You can start here - http://youtu.be/sO8hiPreNBg

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for basically a web-based REST testing tool, try the Firefox RESTClient plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a framework ?
You may take a look here:

1. [AppJS](http://appjs.org/) for Linux, Windows and Mac using HTML, CSS and Javascript
2. [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) : cross-platform using ActionScript/FLEX or HTML/Javascript
3. [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) : HTML/CSS (no support anymore)
4. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) : mainly used for cross-phone-platform, but [here](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-windows)'s an Windows implementation of it (you should read the README.md ...)
5. You may also check [this](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/desktop-apps-with-html5-and-the-mozilla-web-runtime/) from Mozilla